# Tensor flow warning: your input ran out of data

Tags: tensorflow

Good evening,
I keep having this warning on tensorflow near the end of the first epoch. 'WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 78 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.'

In the following I report my model.

```html
INIT_LR = 0.0001
EPOCHS = 10
BS=32

aug = ImageDataGenerator(
  rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
  rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)
```

I stil cannot understand why. I've put both steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS and similiar for validation_steps, but this warning is still there, do you know what could be the problem?
I'm using a dataset of 10.000 samples, and data is divided in 75% train and 25% valid

Answer (score 0):

Warning doesn't harm your code execution.
You can suppress these Warnings using below code

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```